# Permission denied when curling a url

Tags: curl

So I'm just trying to curl this url (http://www.seine-saint-denis.gouv.fr/booking/create/2616).

In my Mac it returns the page correctly. When I try the same thing in a headless Linux, I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /booking/create/2616
on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

And its not because I need to specify the user agent, the curl already works with the same URL in my Mac!

But when I try to curl just the url origin (http://www.seine-saint-denis.gouv.fr) on the Linux instance, it does work.

Comment: Maybe you can dump the exchange with wireshark on the to OS to see the difference

Comment: just an fyi, I'm on a Mac and getting a 403 from the curl and from just entering the uri in a chrome browser, so don't think it's necessarily because of Linux

Comment: and when you try just the url origin ?

Comment: I can access (http://www.seine-saint-denis.gouv.fr) fine